# How to run a processwire site on my mac?

Tags: php, mysql, processwire

I have an existing site, using processwire framework, sitting on a godaddy server and working fine. I want to run a version of it on my mac. I've downloaded the whole site folder to my mac and tried to open the home.php page through the browser with the php listener, but I'm getting an HTML page with a bit of code and than the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in <b>/Users/yotamhacohen/Downloads/ProcessWire-master/site/templates/home.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

I'm kind of new into web developing (especially DB) so if you give any instructions regarding that, please be specific. Thanks.

Comment: You don't access templates directly with ProcessWire. The idea is to create a template and then create a page and assign it to that template. You will be better off asking in the [ProcessWire forums](http://processwire.com/talk/). Might I also recommend that you read through the [docs](http://processwire.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess for a start you should put your site into `/Users/yotamhacohen/Sites/ProcessWire-master/` and then access it in your browser via http://localhost/~yotamhacohen/ProcessWire-master/. This is where your local [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) setup expects your code. If you're new to all this, you might want to learn first how to set up your local server properly.

eg. http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

You also need to move the content of the database. This is where your contents are stored.